# What exactly does "empty stack" mean in the context of "callback queue"?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with understanding how the event loop works in Javascript.
After watching Philip Rogers and Jake Archibald's videos I thought I have some sort of understanding of what should happen when the stack is empty, but then a simple attempt to expand on the classic example of

```
console.log('a');
setTimeout(() => console.log('b'), 0);
console.log('c');
```

broke my mind just a bit. These are the questions I had in my mind:

- Why doesn't *console.log('b')* gets executed immediately?
- Shouldn't the call stack be empty after the *setTimeout()* is called? Shouldn't we get the next operation from the callback queue since the stack is empty? Why not, what is it that I've missed?

Then I thought that may be it could do with Web APIs and tried to do something more concrete like

```
console.log('a');
setTimeout(() => console.log('b'), 0);
 
* some heavy calculations *

console.log('c')
```

But it works just the same! We still get the 'b' last, even though there clearly should've been enough time to put *console.log('b')* into the callback queue and before *console.log('c')*  since the stack is empty after the * heavy calculations *.

Please, could you help me understand what exactly is an empty stack?

If it only means finishing executing all the synchronous commands, why are we even talking about the call stack when it doesn't matter since basically the entire callback queue should just be rebased to the end of the script? Or can there be a different scenario? I'm so heavily confused by this that don't even know where to look for the answer anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the call stack be empty after the `setTimeout()` is called?

No. There is an invisible "global" stack frame for the execution of the whole `<script>`. Only when that has finished, the call stack is truly empty.

> Why are we even talking about the call stack when it doesn't matter since basically the entire callback queue should just be rebased to the end of the script?

Because the execution of a script is just one of many cases where the event loop runs javascript code. Most of them are callback function calls, like that to the `() => console.log('b')` function. Consider the example

```
setTimeout(function one() {
  setTimeout(function two() {
    console.log('c');
  }, 0);
  console.log('b');
}, 0);
console.log('a');
```

Here the first `setTimeout` call and the logging of `a` run on script stack frame, but the second `setTimeout` call and the logging of `b` run on the stack frame of the call to `one`. The callback `two` must not be called until `one` has finished (the call stack is empty), and there's no "end of the script" to talk about.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't console.log('b') gets executed immediately?

Because the function that contains that expression is passed to `setTimeout` which puts it on a queue of functions to be called later when:

- The event loop isn't busy running another function
- The time specified in the second argument for `setTimeout` has passed
- The minimum time for `setTimeout` has passed

> Shouldn't the call stack be empty after the setTimeout() is called?

No. There's `console.log('c');` still to run in the function that is currently on top of that stack.

> But it works just the same! We still get the 'b' last, even though there clearly should've been enough time to put console.log('b') into the callback queue and before console.log('c') since the stack is empty after the * heavy calculations *.

The main event loop only does one thing at a time. It is too busy finishing the current work to look to see if there is anything on the queue that is due to run.

> If it only means finishing executing all the synchronous commands, why are we even talking about the call stack when it doesn't matter since basically the entire callback queue should just be rebased to the end of the script?

It isn't just a matter of finishing everything synchronous.

Something asynchronous might be ready and get called before the timeouted function.

Comment: Right, thanks. I'm probably thinking in terms of executing script top-to-bottom cause that's all I had to consider up until now. That helps